# Get consecutive occurence based on grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to get groups of consecutive occurences grouped by hosts and sorted by time. Ideally I need the groups that meet a certain treshold and `isCorrect == false`

Example

```
Time    |   Host    |   isCorrect   |
-------------------------------------
10:01   |   HostA   |   true        |
10:02   |   HostB   |   true        |
10:03   |   HostA   |   false       |
10:15   |   HostA   |   false       |
10:16   |   HostA   |   false       |
10:18   |   HostB   |   false       |
10:20   |   HostA   |   true        |
10:21   |   HostA   |   true        |
10:22   |   HostB   |   false       |
10:23   |   HostB   |   false       |
```

Threshold: >=3

Would results in 2 groups of

```
Time    |   Host    |   isCorrect   | Group
--------------------------------------------
10:03   |   HostA   |   false       |1
10:15   |   HostA   |   false       |1
10:16   |   HostA   |   false       |1

10:18   |   HostB   |   false       |2
10:22   |   HostB   |   false       |2
10:23   |   HostB   |   false       |2
```

I was reading https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dataframe-group-by-consecutive-certain-values-a6ed8e5d8cc but could not find a way to group by Host first.

Comment: What do you mean by: `get groups of consecutive occurences` ? Is this after you have group by Host?

Comment: yes after grouping by hosts

Comment: So you could have more than 3 values for HostA?

Comment: yes it can have between 0 and hundreds of values. I need all the ones where at least 3 consecutive occurences exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter `False` values by inverting mask with `~` and sorting values (if necessary), then filter groups with threshold and last create `Group` column by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df = df[~df['isCorrect']].sort_values(['Host','Time'])
mask = df['Host'].map(df['Host'].value_counts()) >= 3

df = df[mask].copy()
df['Group'] = pd.factorize(df['Host'])[0] + 1
print (df)

    Time   Host  isCorrect  Group
2  10:03  HostA      False      1
3  10:15  HostA      False      1
4  10:16  HostA      False      1
5  10:18  HostB      False      2
8  10:22  HostB      False      2
9  10:23  HostB      False      2
```

If grouping by consecutive `False`s:

```
m = ~df['isCorrect']
df['Group'] = df['isCorrect'].cumsum()[m]

df = df[m].sort_values(['Host','Time'])

mask = df.groupby(['Group', 'Host'])['Group'].transform('size') >= 3

df = df[mask].copy()
df['Group'] = pd.factorize(df['Host'])[0] + 1
print (df)
    Time   Host  isCorrect  Group
2  10:03  HostA      False      1
3  10:15  HostA      False      1
4  10:16  HostA      False      1
```

Comment: nice. How would I find the different groups? As HostA could have a second group later in the day